# How to receive message published on a topic using mqtt protocol in spring:jms application?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic, publish, publish-subscribe

I am new to activemq.

I have a publisher which publish a message to a topic using mqtt protocol. And now I want to write a subscriber using Spring + JMS which will listen for the message on that topic.

I have following questions:

1) Can I have a same topic if I write the subscriber using tcp protocol.I mean to say, publisher will use MQTT to publish on a topic and subscriber will listen on that topic using TCP broker URL.

2) If above is not possible then how can I write a subscriber using spring + jms that will listen and receive the messages published on the topic using mqtt ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Consider to use Spring Integration MQTT Support: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/mqtt.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you even try? Yes, it works pretty much as you expect it to. MQTT msgs gets converted to JMS if you try read it with JMS (OpenWire).

From [web site](http://activemq.apache.org/mqtt.html):

> Message transformations
>
> MQTT messages are transformed into an JMS
>   ByteMessage. Conversely, the body of any JMS Message is converted to a
>   byte buffer to be the payload of an MQTT message.